# react and php and mobile

Tags: php, reactjs, mobile

I am using react for my frontend, PHP and MySQL for the backend. React is running on localhost, port 3000 and xampp server is in localhost, port 80.

I am getting data from MySQL to php parse to json format. For the frontend, I used axios API to call the data.

While I am in browser, I am able to see the data, but when I access the same page from mobile, I can see only the tables not the json data.

[image]

[image: From PC]

[image: From Mobile]

Comment: Have you tried using the site from another laptop or PC in your network where you have access to the network console? Inspecting it, or the browser's error console, might help to check for errors

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are running your application locally, and wont be able to access localhost on your mobile (because as the word itself suggests its LOCALhost). If your mobile is on the same network as your desktop you can access the site from your computers local ip address.

Comment: I am able to acces it ,, see the pictures

Comment: I understand you can access from desktop, but I am explaining why you cant access it from you mobile phone.

Comment: Try using the web dev tools of your browser (helpful link: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-simulate-mobile-devices-with-device-mode-in-chrome/), and check if the problem is with the html, but would need to see the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your front-end is configured to use `http://localhost` as the back-end url ? Which means that when running on your phone, its using the phone host as the back-end url :)

Try setting the back-end url to http://192.168.1.99 on the front-end.

Comment: No worries ! Do not hesitate to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Change API url to:

```
http://192.168.1.99/assets/data.php
```

You used localhost/assets/data.php, but your xampp was installed on your PC, not on your mobile, so your mobile can't access to this.

Comment: Thanks Dear..You helped me...I changed as per ur advise.....
 fetch('http://192.168.1.99/itassets/server/alldata.php')

Comment: I recommend using root relative URLs so that moving from localhost development to production doesn't require any changes, i.e. using URL `/assets/data.php` instead of the absolute URL so that it doesn't conflict either with domain name or protocol

Answer (score 0):

Hi to test it on mobile you could also used Remote Device from chrome developer tools.

For details you can check on this Link
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews